# How to extact a Python dictionary in another dictionary and return some of his keys

Tags: python, dictionary

I am new to the concept of dictionary in Python. I have this current dictionary that contain another dictionary :

```
{
   "count" : 3,
   "document_type" : "list",
   "documents" : [
      {
         "adminc_id" : "5d834741f1e79df70494d614",
         "archived" : false,
         "company_code" : "AAAAAA",
         "created_at" : "2020-09-16T13:07:54.482000+00:00",
         "customer_label" : "pomme",
         "customer_ref" : "fruit",
         "delivered_at" : "2018-11-07T00:00:00+00:00",
         "document_type" : "service",
         "state" : "delivered",
         "subscribed_at" : "2018-11-07T00:00:00+00:00",
         "tag" : "EX46V4YQ",
         "techc_id" : "5d834741f1e79df70494d614",
         "type" : "energy",
         "updated_at" : "2020-09-16T13:07:54.482000+00:00"
      },
      {
         "adminc_id" : "5f6e162958becabad3b64047",
         "archived" : false,
         "company_code" : "BBBBBB",
         "created_at" : "2020-09-25T16:18:05.807000+00:00",
         "document_type" : "service",
         "state" : "subscribed",
         "tag" : "T94893JQ",
         "techc_id" : "5f6e162958becabad3b64047",
         "type" : "telephony",
         "updated_at" : "2020-09-25T16:18:05.807000+00:00"
      },
      {
         "adminc_id" : "5f62071fa6dbcad5bf20d832",
         "archived" : false,
         "company_code" : "AAAAAA",
         "created_at" : "2020-09-25T16:15:27.590000+00:00",
         "document_type" : "service",
         "state" : "subscribed",
         "tag" : "TV47X3XQ",
         "techc_id" : "5f62071fa6dbcad5bf20d832",
         "type" : "telephony",
         "updated_at" : "2020-09-25T16:15:27.590000+00:00"
      }
   ],
   "limit" : 50,
   "offset" : 0
}
```

I am trying to return the dictionary `documents` with the keys value "tag" and "company_code". I tried to extract the dictionary document with a dict.get('document') but the result is returned with the square bracket which does not seems to be a dictionary format :

```
[
   {
      "adminc_id" : "5d834741f1e79df70494d614",
      "archived" : false,
      "company_code" : "AAAAAA",
      "created_at" : "2020-09-16T13:07:54.482000+00:00",
      "customer_label" : "pomme",
      "customer_ref" : "fruit",
      "delivered_at" : "2018-11-07T00:00:00+00:00",
      "document_type" : "service",
      "state" : "delivered",
      "subscribed_at" : "2018-11-07T00:00:00+00:00",
      "tag" : "EX46V4YQ",
      "techc_id" : "5d834741f1e79df70494d614",
      "type" : "energy",
      "updated_at" : "2020-09-16T13:07:54.482000+00:00"
   },
   {
      "adminc_id" : "5f6e162958becabad3b64047",
      "archived" : false,
      "company_code" : "BBBBBB",
      "created_at" : "2020-09-25T16:18:05.807000+00:00",
      "document_type" : "service",
      "state" : "subscribed",
      "tag" : "T94893JQ",
      "techc_id" : "5f6e162958becabad3b64047",
      "type" : "telephony",
      "updated_at" : "2020-09-25T16:18:05.807000+00:00"
   },
   {
      "adminc_id" : "5f62071fa6dbcad5bf20d832",
      "archived" : false,
      "company_code" : "AAAAAA",
      "created_at" : "2020-09-25T16:15:27.590000+00:00",
      "document_type" : "service",
      "state" : "subscribed",
      "tag" : "TV47X3XQ",
      "techc_id" : "5f62071fa6dbcad5bf20d832",
      "type" : "telephony",
      "updated_at" : "2020-09-25T16:15:27.590000+00:00"
   }
]
```

I don't know how to manage a square bracket format, I need to get this result at the end :

```
{
      "company_code" : "AAAAAA",
      "tag" : "EX46V4YQ"
},
{
      "company_code" : "BBBBBB",
      "tag" : "T94893JQ"
},
{
      "company_code" : "AAAAAA",
      "tag" : "TV47X3XQ",
}
```

Can anyone kindly help me understand how it works ? Thank you.

Best regards.

Comment: The "square bracket format" means your result is a [_list_](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists), which is also what `yourdict["documents"]` is. You can find a bunch of good tutorials on how to use lists on the internet.

Comment: The `documents` entry isn't a dictionary.  It's a list of dictionaries.  Remember: `[...]` is a list, while `{...}` is a dictionary (or set).

Answer (score 2):

> ***Dictionary** in python is one of the most important things you really need to get in touch with in terms of *Data Structure in Python**

If you want to extract specific value from sub-dictionary, you can use the term of *2-d boundary*.

For instance,

```py
books = {"recipes": {"blt": ["bacon", "lettuce", "tomato", "bread"],
                     "beans_on_toast": ["beans", "bread"],
                     "scrambles eggs": ["eggs", "butter", "milk"],
                     "soup": ["tin of soap"],
                     "pasta": ["pasta", "cheese"]},

         "maintenance": {"stuck": ["oil"],
                         "loose": ["gaffer tape"]}}
```

```py
print(books["recipes"]["soup"])
print(books["recipes"]["scrambles eggs"])

print(books["maintenance"]["loose"])
```

This `book` Dictionary is complex `disc`. If you want to access sub-key of one of its values, you will need to use the term of *2-d boundary*.

After debugging This'll be the result:

```
['tin of soap']
['eggs', 'butter', 'milk']
['gaffer tape']
```

You can also check these *Github* links for more features and examples about the dictionary and data structure overall in python;

[Section05.9_ShelveChallenge01_Using_Dictionary](https://github.com/DrStarkXavier/complete-python-course-full-guided/blob/main/Section05_input%26output/Section05.9_ShelveChallenge01.py)

[Data Structure in Python](https://github.com/DrStarkXavier/complete-python-course-full-guided/tree/main/Section04_PythonDatastructure_Dictionary%26Sets)

Answer (score 1):

**Solution:**

This code snippet might solve your issue:

```
in_dict = {
   "count" : 3,
   "document_type" : "list",
   "documents" : [
      {
         "adminc_id" : "5d834741f1e79df70494d614",
         "archived" : False,
         "company_code" : "AAAAAA",
         "created_at" : "2020-09-16T13:07:54.482000+00:00",
         "customer_label" : "pomme",
         "customer_ref" : "fruit",
         "delivered_at" : "2018-11-07T00:00:00+00:00",
         "document_type" : "service",
         "state" : "delivered",
         "subscribed_at" : "2018-11-07T00:00:00+00:00",
         "tag" : "EX46V4YQ",
         "techc_id" : "5d834741f1e79df70494d614",
         "type" : "energy",
         "updated_at" : "2020-09-16T13:07:54.482000+00:00"
      },
      {
         "adminc_id" : "5f6e162958becabad3b64047",
         "archived" : False,
         "company_code" : "BBBBBB",
         "created_at" : "2020-09-25T16:18:05.807000+00:00",
         "document_type" : "service",
         "state" : "subscribed",
         "tag" : "T94893JQ",
         "techc_id" : "5f6e162958becabad3b64047",
         "type" : "telephony",
         "updated_at" : "2020-09-25T16:18:05.807000+00:00"
      },
      {
         "adminc_id" : "5f62071fa6dbcad5bf20d832",
         "archived" : False,
         "company_code" : "AAAAAA",
         "created_at" : "2020-09-25T16:15:27.590000+00:00",
         "document_type" : "service",
         "state" : "subscribed",
         "tag" : "TV47X3XQ",
         "techc_id" : "5f62071fa6dbcad5bf20d832",
         "type" : "telephony",
         "updated_at" : "2020-09-25T16:15:27.590000+00:00"
      }
   ],
   "limit" : 50,
   "offset" : 0
}
```

This loop will iterate over the dictionaries that are present inside the list, as shown in the question:

```
for inner_dict in in_dict['documents']:
    print(inner_dict)*
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
{'adminc_id': '5d834741f1e79df70494d614', 'archived': False, 'company_code': 'AAAAAA', 'created_at': '2020-09-16T13:07:54.482000+00:00', 'customer_label': 'pomme', 'customer_ref': 'fruit', 'delivered_at': '2018-11-07T00:00:00+00:00', 'document_type': 'service', 'state': 'delivered', 'subscribed_at': '2018-11-07T00:00:00+00:00', 'tag': 'EX46V4YQ', 'techc_id': '5d834741f1e79df70494d614', 'type': 'energy', 'updated_at': '2020-09-16T13:07:54.482000+00:00'}
{'adminc_id': '5f6e162958becabad3b64047', 'archived': False, 'company_code': 'BBBBBB', 'created_at': '2020-09-25T16:18:05.807000+00:00', 'document_type': 'service', 'state': 'subscribed', 'tag': 'T94893JQ', 'techc_id': '5f6e162958becabad3b64047', 'type': 'telephony', 'updated_at': '2020-09-25T16:18:05.807000+00:00'}
{'adminc_id': '5f62071fa6dbcad5bf20d832', 'archived': False, 'company_code': 'AAAAAA', 'created_at': '2020-09-25T16:15:27.590000+00:00', 'document_type': 'service', 'state': 'subscribed', 'tag': 'TV47X3XQ', 'techc_id': '5f62071fa6dbcad5bf20d832', 'type': 'telephony', 'updated_at': '2020-09-25T16:15:27.590000+00:00'}
```

**NOTE: You can select the required keys using `inner_dict[KEY_NAME]` **